# problemas con las migraciones FK en laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, artisan

No entiendo porque me sigue arrojando el error de que las FK estan incorrectamente formadas.
Lo he revisado una y otra vez y me sale el mismo error.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('tutores', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('ID_Tutor');
        $table->unsignedInteger('ID_Usuario');
        $table->string('carnet');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('apellido_paterno');
        $table->string('apellido_materno');
        $table->date('nacimiento');
        $table->string('telefono');
        $table->string('direccion');
        $table->foreign('ID_Usuario')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

Sigue diciéndome que hay un problema con la ´foreign key´ y no se cual podria ser.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ue_db`.`tutores` (errno: 150 
"Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `
tutores` add constraint `tutores_id_usuario_foreign` foreign key (`ID_Usuario`) references 
`users` (`id`))
```

Comment: Prueba unsignedBigInteger en vez de unsignedInteger

Comment: Aun me da el problema... No entiendo que pueda ser

Answer (score 0):

Si reemplaza 'ID_Usuario' por 'user_id' en la tabla tutores continua el problema?

nombre de la tabla a la que hace referencia en singular y luego agregarle el sufijo _id, es decir, user_id

```
Schema::create('tutores', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('ID_Tutor');
        $table->foreignId('user_id');
        $table->string('carnet');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('apellido_paterno');
        $table->string('apellido_materno');
        $table->date('nacimiento');
        $table->string('telefono');
        $table->string('direccion');
    });
```

Comment: Lo intente. pero aun me da el problema

Comment: Edite la respuesta. ¿Y así te sirve?

Comment: El problema parece haber sido el campo 'id' de users... Breeze lo crea con de tipo ´id´,  y SQL al momento de usarlo como referencia no lo interpreta asi...

Answer (score 0):

Bien, despues de probar y probar con uno y otro metodo creo haber dado con la solucion.
El problema es el ´user.id´
Yo tengo el modulo de Breeze implementado, este modulo crea las tablas ´user, password´y algunas otras mas, el problema es que el ´user.id´ lo crea con el campo ´id´ asi...

```
 $table->id();
```

por algun motivo, al realizar las migraciones, ´SQL´ a pesar de que si lo registra como ´PK´, cuando intenta asignar este campo como ´Referencia´ de una **FK** no lo hace... Por lo que debes modificar el user.id y reemplazarlo por algo mas asi...

```
$table->increments('id);
```

Con esto deberia de funcionar. Pdta. Es una coñada que hayan sacado los *backtips* para resaltar el codigo entre el texto, o será un error actual, no lo se.